# Problem installing matplotlib or certifi with pip

Tags: python, installation, pip

This is on an arm based machine runing arch linux.

```
 ERROR: Requested certifi>=2020.06.20 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5e/a0/5f06e1e1d463903cf0c0eebeb751791119ed7a4b3737fdc9a77f1cdfb51f/certifi-2020.12.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=719a74fb9e33b9bd44cc7f3a8d94bc35e4049deebe19ba7d8e108280cfd59830 has different version in metadata: '2020.12.5'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 75, in fetch_build_egg
        subprocess.check_call(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/tmp/tmponkebyxp', '--quiet', 'certifi>=2020.06.20']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

```
 The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-94nlrun8/matplotlib/setup.py", line 256, in <module>
        setup(  # Finally, pass this all along to distutils to do the heavy lifting.
      File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 152, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 147, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 721, in fetch_build_eggs
        resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
      File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 766, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
      File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1051, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1063, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 780, in fetch_build_egg
        return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 77, in fetch_build_egg
        raise DistutilsError(str(e)) from e
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['/usr/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/tmp/tmponkebyxp', '--quiet', 'certifi>=2020.06.20']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I tryed many of the aswers given on other questions but none of them help me.

The command I ran was `python -m pip install matplotlib`

The same happens if I run `python -m pip install certifi`

Comment: what version of setuptools are you/matplotlib/certifi using? i was having a similar issue and fixed by pinning setuptools to 51.3.3

Comment: I found a workaround. You can install almost every python lib as a package so I installed it via pacman and it works flawlessly. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround. You can install almost any python lib as a package. Easier to do it like this then to fiddle with python as I don't use it very often.